# Change the date format

Tags: r

is there a way to convert `1978-01-31` to `01/31/1978` in R?
I have a field in my data.frame and the date format is in `yyyy-dd-mm` and would like to change it to `mm/dd/yyyy` - I have looked around but could not find any example of how this can be done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `format(as.Date('1978-01-31'), '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: @Jaap Thanks, that was quick. What an awesome solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
z <- as.Date('1978-01-31')
z
[1] "1978-01-31"

as.character(z, format = '%m/%d/%Y')

[1] "01/31/1978"

# or if you want to keep the Date format

z2 <- format(z, '%m/%d/%Y')

z2

[1] "01/31/1978"
```